# I transferred all of my Pokemon from the PokeBank into Sun/Moon, where is the Nationaal Pokedex?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I just moved all of them into Sun/Moon but the game doesn't seem to notice, even if I move a Pokemon I got from another game into the party.

How do I get the National Dex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, the national dex is not in the game. The national dex is a part of the Pokemon Bank now if you go to the menu then click Pokedex.